# How can HTML rendering be conditionally managed when integrating DataTables initialization with a Spring Boot backend API for server-side processing?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, datatable, thymeleaf

**Conditionally Rendering DataTables Actions Based on User Roles in a Spring Boot Application**
I have a DataTables implementation in my Spring Boot application, and I'm trying to conditionally render actions in the DataTable based on the user's roles. The DataTable includes an action column that should display edit, delete, and view buttons only if the user has the EDITOR role.

Here's the Thymeleaf code for conditionally rendering the delete button:

```
<form th:if="${#lists.contains(roles, 'EDITOR')}" style="display:inline !important;" th:action="@{/touchPoint/delete/}" method="post" onsubmit="return confirm('Do you really want to delete this Assignment? This action cannot be reversed.');">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" th:value="*{TouchPointID}"/>
    <button class="form-command btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
</form>
```

In my DataTables configuration, I'm sending the user roles in the API response:

```
// Controller API method
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = authentication.getAuthorities();

        List<String> authorityStrings = authorities.stream()
                .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
response.put("authorities", authorityStrings); // places the authorities in the 'authorities' obj
```

And here's the relevant part of my DataTables configuration, the actions columns:

```
"columns": [
    // ... other columns
    {
        "data": null,
        "render": function (data, type, row) {
            var authorities = json.authorities || [];
            var hasEditorRole = authorities.includes('EDITOR');

            if (hasEditorRole) {
                return '<button class="edit-button">Edit</button>';
            } else {
                return 'No action';
            }
        }
    }
    // ... other columns
],
```

Answer (score 1):

The datatable is populated by javascript (jQuery) and Thymeleaf has nothing to do with it.

Saying the above, you can load the `authorities` in the html page as a json array and check for the permission when constructing the rows in the datatable.

```
// somewhere in the html
<script th:inline="javascript">
    // authorities as a json array
    const authorities = /*[[${authorities}]]*/ '';
    const deleteUrl = /*[[@{drink/delete}]]*/ ''; // we will use this later, maybe this is resolving to the path "drink/delete-drink"
</script>
```

Usually the rows in the datatable result set are represented by an array of objects. If we are displaying a array of 'Drink' objects, most probably the dataset in the response would be something like:

```
"data": [
   {
      "drinkId" : 1,
      "name" : "Coca cola"
   },
   {
      "drinkId" : 2,
      "name" : "Pepsi"
   },
   {
      "drinkId" : 3,
      "name" : "Expresso"
   }
]
```

Now the conditional rendering is done purely with javascript, no thymeleaf here.

```
"columns": [
    // ... other columns
    {
        "data": null,
        "render": function (data, type, row) {
            var hasDeleteRole = authorities.includes('DELETE');

            if (hasDeleteRole) {
                // just an example of how to use the delete url and the drinkId which is unique per row
                return '<a href="deleteUrl + \'?id=' + row.drinkId + '\'"/>'
                // after resolving the above, it should something look like this in the html <a href="http://localhost/drink/delete-drink?id=3"/>
            } else {
                return 'No action';
            }
        }
    }
    // ... other columns
],
```